# Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar breaks FAB cradle

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Why does using

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="iconColor">@color/greyBlue</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/blue_gradient_background</item>
</style>
```

Result in

[image]

And extending from MaterialComponents like so:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="iconColor">@color/greyBlue</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/blue_gradient_background</item>
</style>
```

Results in:

[image]

Here is AppBar code:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
    app:hideOnScroll="true">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottomappbar_menu" />

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
    app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

If anyone has any idea or a point in the right direction. I'm at a loss here, especially since official documentation says to extend from MaterialComponents (https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/)

I am using `"com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"`

**Edit:** Updating to `"com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03"` does nothing of significance except it changes run-time color of FAB background.
Preview now looks like this: 
[image]

**Another edit:** Here is image showing that nothing has changed run-time except for the color which I mentioned.
[image]

Comment: *Preview now looks like this* don't look at the preview, look at the actual rendering on a device. Preview is not runtime

Comment: Even if it was preview bug (which is not), that would still warrant an explanation. I updated original post with runtime image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the BottomNavigationView backgroundColor to transparent and the elevation to 0dp

Example:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
    app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
    app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp"
    app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:hideOnScroll="true"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar$Behavior">
    
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/defaultNavigationContentColor"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/defaultNavigationContentColor"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_bottom_menu" />
    
</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
    
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tint="@color/defaultToolbarContentColor"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/primaryColor"
    app:tint="@color/defaultToolbarContentColor"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton$Behavior"/>
```

To align your Navigation items a bit better add a placeholder in the middle and disable it

Example:

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/activityBottomDelete"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_24"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/placeholder"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:title="" />

    <item android:id="@+id/activityBottomDirection"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/direction"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_autorenew_24"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```